# ExtJS left toolbar is horizontal and not vertical

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm using ExtJS to create Left toolbar but the icons are still horizontal instead of vertical.
Any idea why ?!

This is how I create the toolbar :

```
function createActions() {
    actions['nav'] = createAction(panControl,"","Pan", "pan48", true, "navGroup");
    actions['zoomin'] = createAction(zoomboxInControl,"", "ZoomIn", "zoomin48", true, "navGroup");
    actions['zoomout'] = createAction(zoomboxOutControl,"", "ZoomOut", "zoomout48", true,"navGroup");
}

function createAction(control, text, title, iconCls, allowDepress, toggleGroup, disabled) {
    return Ext.create('GeoExt.Action', {
        control: control,
        map: map,
        scale: 'large',
        allowDepress: allowDepress,
        toggleGroup: toggleGroup,
        group: toggleGroup,
        disabled: disabled,
        hideText: true,
        tooltip:
                {
                    text: text,
                    title: title
                },
        iconCls: iconCls
    })
}

function createToolBar() {        

    toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
        id: 'toolbar',
        enableOverflow: true,
        items: [
         Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', actions["nav"])
                  , Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', actions["zoomin"])
                  , Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', actions["zoomout"])
                  , Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', actions["maxExt"])
        ]
    });
```

and what I get looks like this basically :

[image]

any idea ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the vbox layout.

```
function createToolBar() {        

toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    id: 'toolbar',
    layout: 'vbox', <----- this should do it
    enableOverflow: true,
    items: [
     Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', actions["nav"])
              , Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', actions["zoomin"])
              , Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', actions["zoomout"])
              , Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', actions["maxExt"])
    ]
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/awesomepeter/Ts7Va/2/

Comment: That's what the vertical config does, just configures it with a `vbox` layout.

Comment: This is working , I managed to achieve the same using : "columns: 1".

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it to be vertical by using the [`vertical`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar-cfg-vertical) config.

Comment: halfway there , I've created groups , now the groups are vertically but the icons inside the group are still horizontal.

Can that be vertically also ?